# Updating node.js driven content from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

I'm trying to achieve a dynamic update of a ul by selecting from a dropdown list. Also, I'm entirely new to node.js ..

In node.js:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.json(searchYT(res.valDDl));
});

var searchTerm="Astrix";

function searchYT(term)
{
  search(term, opts, function(err, results) {
    if(err) return console.log(err);

    var str = JSON.stringify(results,null,4);

    fs.writeFile("./results.json", str, function(err) {
      if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
      }
    });
  });
}

searchYT(searchTerm);

app.locals.resultsData = require('./results.json');

module.exports = app;
```

In index.ejs

```
  <select id="playDDL" name="playDDL" onchange="reportDDL(this.value)">
    <option value="Astrix">Astrix</option>
    <option value="Deadmau5">Deadmau5</option>
    <option value="Tiesto">Tiesto</option>
    <option value="Avicii">Avicii</option>
    <option value="Markus Schulz">Markus Schulz</option>
    <option value="Armin Van Buuren">Armin Van Buuren</option>
  </select>
  <ul id="playUL">
    <% resultsData.forEach(function(item){ %>
      <li><a href="<%= item.link %>" target="_blank"><img src="<%= item.thumbnails.default.url %>"/></a></li>
    <% }); %>
  </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function reportDDL(val) {
        $.ajax({
          url: '/',
          type: 'GET',
          data: {valDDL: val}
        });

        $.getJSON("/", function( data ) {
          window.alert("test");
        }
          var items = [];
          $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
            //
          });
      }
    </script>
```

As you would notice, I'm trying to use javascript to identify a change in the selection of the drop down menu and somehow change the search term in node and call the searchYT() function and then have the ul rendered again with the new dropdown list selection.
What am I missing?

Comment: You need an ajax call from the client to call a route in your node.js server where you can return the results.  Then, the calling code takes the results and inserts it into the page.  Javascript in the browser runs only in the browser and cannot directly call functions in your server.  You have to use a networking call (Ajax call) from the browser to communicate with your server.

Comment: Isn't that what the "$.ajax({type: "POST" tries to accomplish? I'm unsure how to proceed..

Comment: That's a piece of the right idea, but you need to pass a URL to the ajax call and that needs to go to a specific route in your node.js server which needs to return the proper results and the `reportDDL()` function needs to then process the results and modify the current page.  Your current ajax call does nothing.  It isn't targetted at a specific URL and it doesn't process any results.

Comment: I've updated my original code/post to reflect the latest changes. I'm not too familiar with POST/GET handling with node.js and as you can see, I'm trying to test if a response is received and it isn't. Please help out with valid code if you can.

Comment: What you have now is not any closer.  If you have jQuery, by all means use it for your ajax call as it simplifies things greatly.  On the client side, you were just missing a URL and a response handler (missing other thingson the server side).  Just follow some of the examples in the jQuery doc.  Perhaps you should find and follow a simple tutorial on make an ajax call from jQuery to express.  I'm sure there are many on the net.

Comment: Changes made. I followed a tutorial to the letter. Still no give! What's wrong with my GET request?

Comment: The ajax call in the browser looks right now.  The `app.get()` looks right.  I can't tell if the rest of your node.js server is set up properly or not to make it all work because you don't show that code.  Is jQuery loaded in your web page?  Are you getting console errors in the browser or errors in your server?  Do any other web requests work for your server?

Comment: Just further updated my solution. The jquery finally works and the test window.alert was triggering. Now, if you could, please help me understand how I should fetch the JSON data being sent from the server. Is the $.getJSON call appropriate? This time, the window.alert is not being triggered again indicating a new problem, I'd assume.

Comment: Iterative questions like this where we are being asked to follow one problem after another after another are not how StackOverflow works.  You do your initial research and troubleshooting, you post a problem clearly explaining where you got stuck and then you hopefully get an answer to THAT specific problem.  If you then have other problems after that and you've done your own homework on them, you post additional questions.  The way you are doing things here does not fit with StackOverflow at all.

Comment: If you want a hint, see what `searchYT()` actually returns that you're turning into JSON and sending back to the client.  Hint, it's an async operation with no return value.  But, I'm moving on here as this question does not follow any of the StackOverflow guidelines.

Comment: I understand. Thanks @jfriend00